# What is the origin of lighting candles on birthdays?

Tags: cultural-history, everyday-life

What is the origin people start lighting the candles on birthdays.

Also please explain what is the reason/logic behind it?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.awpnow.com/main/2019/04/26/fun-fact-friday-why-do-we-blow-out-birthday-candles/) help?

Answer (score -1):

There are many theories about the origins of birthday candles. I quoting some of them from internet

> Some believe that the tradition of birthday candles began in Ancient
> Greece, when people brought cakes adorned with lit candles to the
> temple of Artemis, goddess of the hunt. The candles were lit to make
> them glow like the moon, a popular symbol associated with Artemis.
>
> Many ancient cultures also believed that smoke carried their prayers
> to the heavens. Today’s tradition of making wishes before blowing out
> your birthday candles may have started with that belief.
>
> Others believe that the tradition of birthday candles started with the
> Germans. In 1746, Count Ludwig Von Zinzindorf celebrated his birthday
> with an extravagant festival. And, of course, a cake and candles:
> “there was a Cake as large as any Oven could be found to bake it, and
> Holes made in the Cake according to the Years of the Person’s Age,
> every one having a Candle stuck into it, and one in the Middle.”
>
> The Germans also celebrated with birthday candles during Kinderfest, a
> birthday celebration for children in the 1700s. A single birthday
> candle was lit and placed on the cake to symbolize the “light of
> life.”
>
> Some scholars believe that other meanings have also been attached to
> the use of candles on cakes. People may have believed that the smoke
> from the candles carried their wishes and prayers to gods who lived in
> the skies. Others probably believed the smoke helped to ward off evil
> spirits.

Source: [Mentalfloss](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/54069/why-do-we-blow-out-candles-birthday-cakes), [Awpnow](https://www.awpnow.com/main/2019/04/26/fun-fact-friday-why-do-we-blow-out-birthday-candles/)

Today, we still put birthday candles on cakes. Many people still hold
superstitious beliefs about them, too. For example,

> Many people believe that the birthday boy or girl must make a silent
> wish before blowing out the candles. If all the candles are blown out
> in one breath, the wish will come true, and the person will have good
> luck throughout the year.
>
> On the other hand, if it takes more than one breath to blow out all
> the candles or if the person tells someone what the wish was, it will
> supposedly not come true.

Source: [Awpnow](https://www.awpnow.com/main/2019/04/26/fun-fact-friday-why-do-we-blow-out-birthday-candles/)